# Any insight on how to solve this inequality: n! <= 10^6?

Tags: python

I have been working on dealing with n! <= 10^6 in python by using sympy.solver. For example, the below is my code:

```
import sympy as sy

print(sy.solve_univariate_inequality(sy.factorial(n) <= 10**6,n))
```

I tried solve_univariate_inequality and solve methods but none of them worked. The error was "raise NotImplementedError('solveset is unable to solve this equation.')"

I'm curious if there's any other way to deal with this inequality. Any insight please?

Comment: Thank you guys for the help :)

Answer (score 1):

```
i = 1
factorial = 1
while factorial <= 1_000_000:
    factorial  *= i
    i += 1

print(f"equation valid for n in [1-{i-2}]")
```

Comment: I'll do you one better - `print("n = 9")`. Ha!

Comment: print(''haha'')

Answer (score 0):

From [docs](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/solvers/solvers.html)

```
Currently supported:
  polynomial

  transcendental

  piecewise combinations of the above

  systems of linear and polynomial equations

  systems containing relational expressions
```

Looks like factorial is not supported.

Comment: In what way does this provide insight into how to solve the inequality?

Answer (score 0):

If you approach this problem purely mathematically you can just increment n to get the factorial which exceeds the threshold.

```
results=[]
n=0
n_factorial=1
while n_factorial<=10**6:
    results.append(n)
    print(n,n_factorial)
    n+=1    
    n_factorial*=n
    
print(results)
```

Output:
0 1
1 1
2 2
3 6
4 24
5 120
6 720
7 5040
8 40320
9 362880
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]